# Dynamic function generation with macros

Tags: common-lisp

I am putting together a macro to generate simple functions of the style:

```
(defun hello ()
  (format t "hello~&"))
```

Each new function will have hello replaced.

```
(defmacro generate-echoers (list)
  `(let ((list-of-functions
         (loop for var in ,list
            collect
              `(defun ,(intern var) ()
                 (format t ,(concatenate var "~&"))))))
  `(progn
     ,list-of-functions)))
```

I developed the above function, which demonstrates conclusively that I have not yet masted quote-times and phases of expansion.

The desired usage is as follows:
    (generate-echoers '("hi" "ping" "pong")) => ;A list of functions that each say their name, as HELLO does above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be simplified and made more correct like this:

```
(defmacro generate-echoers (list)
  `(progn ,@(loop :for var :in list
               :collect `(defun ,(intern (format nil "~:@(~A~)" var)) ()
                           (format t ,(concatenate 'string var "~&"))))))
```

First of all, you've got to splice the `loop`'s result into the generated body.

Also you've forgotten, that `concatenate` takes type parameter and to upcase all your vars (otherwise you'll get function names like `|foo|`).

Comment: The `\`(progn ,@(loop` solved it for me. The rest I sorted out on my own. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

A function to generate:

```
(defun hello ()
  (format t "hello~&"))
```

I would first write a function which creates above code:

```
(defun make-echoers (name)
  `(defun ,(intern (string-upcase name)) ()
     (format t ,(concatenate 'string name "~&"))))
```

Note that symbols are by default uppercase in Common Lisp - so we are using uppercase, too.

Then you can test it:

```
CL-USER 1 > (make-echoers "hello")
(DEFUN HELLO NIL (FORMAT T "hello~&"))
```

Works. Now let's use it:

```
(defmacro generate-echoers (list)
  `(progn ,@(mapcar #'make-echoers list)))
```

Test it:

```
CL-USER 2 > (macroexpand-1 '(generate-echoers ("hi" "ping" "pong")))
(PROGN
  (DEFUN HI NIL (FORMAT T "hi~&"))
  (DEFUN PING NIL (FORMAT T "ping~&"))
  (DEFUN PONG NIL (FORMAT T "pong~&")))
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of making a defun to generate the defun. Problem's already solved, but +1!

Comment: apologies for thread necro; is it possible to alter this so that one can pass a symbol whose value is the list `("hi" "ping" "pong")`, rather than pass the list directly? I tried using `,list`, but this failed.

Comment: @James Porter: you would need to make sure that the symbol value is retrieved. For example by changing the macro to check for a symbol and trying to retrieve a symbol value. Opens another can of worms...

Answer (score 1):

If you pass symbols to the generate-echoers macro (instead of strings), the intern call is no longer necessary:

```
(defmacro generate-echoers (&rest echoers)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (var)
                 `(defun ,var () 
                    (format t ,(format nil "~(~a~)~&" var))))
               echoers)))
```

Comment: The name of the function needs to be SYMBOL or a list according to the Hyperspec. I don't grasp the list part, I think it has to be setf'able. I was passing in a list of strings. I bet you were passing in a list of symbols?

Comment: Also, I like the mapcar. Much cleaner than loop here.